# Capture function and its value using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a text that contains the following function calls:

```
set_name(value:"this is a test");
set_attribute(name:"description", value:"Some
Multi
Line
Value");
```

And I am trying to capture its data so that I get back:
'name'
or
'attribute'

The value just after "set_"

As well as the inside content:

```
value:"this is a test"
```

And

```
name:"description", value:"Some
Multi
Line
Value"
```

Respectively

I tried using this regex:

```
script_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\(([\S\s]*?)\)
```

but it will fail if this is the set_attribute value:

```
set_attribute(name:"description", value:"Some
Multi
(Line)
Value");
```

Because the (first) `)` found there is captured by the regex

I am looking for a regex that would return "attribute" and the content via two group captures:

```
name:"description", value:"Some
Multi
(Line)
Value"
```

Comment: do you mean like this? `set_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\(\w+:"[^"]+"(?:, ?\w+:"[^"]+")*\);` https://regex101.com/r/d1TMat/1/

Comment: If the code is well-formatted, you may rely on `);` at the end of a line as the match end delimiter, `(?ms)^set_(\w+)\((.*?)\);$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GItPoV/1).

Comment: If you need an answer, please specify the pattern requirements, the two suggestions above are based on assumptions, and thus cannot be considered valid answers, just guesses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for clarifying, yes, I am looking for an answer, and yours seems to match the exact need and solution - yes ");" is a valid terminator

Comment: Please add this detail to the question then.

Comment: Like this @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @NoamRathaus I posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63452063/3832970).

Answer (score 2):

The desired strings could be extracted with the following regular expression, with the `single-line` or `DOTALL` flag is set, causing dot to match line terminators.

```
(?<=^set_)\w+(?=\()|(?<=\().*?(?=\);$)
```

The first match is the substring between `set_` and `(`; the second match is the substring between `(` and `)`.

In Ruby, for example, this regex could be used as follows.

```
str = 'set_name(value:"this is a test");'
r = /(?<=^set_)\w+(?=\()|(?<=\().*?(?=\);$)/m

after_set, inside_parens = str.scan(r)
after_set     #=> "name" 
inside_parens #=> "value:\"this is a test\""
```

Note that in Ruby `single-line` or `DOTALL` mode (dot matches line terminators) is denoted `/m`.

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/GxIrS8/2/).

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
/
(?<=^set_)  : positive lookbehind asserts match is preceded by `set_` at
              the beginning of the string
\w+         : match 1+ word characters
(?=\()      : positive lookahead asserts following character is '('
|           : or
(?<=\()     : positive lookbehind asserts match is preceded by '('
.*?         : match 0+ characters, as few as possible
(?=\);$)    : positive lookahead asserts match is followed by ');' at
            : the end of the line
/m          : flag to cause '.' to match line terminators
```

Answer (score 1):

Each line ends with character semicolon. You could add the character in regex after character ).

```
set_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\(([\S\s]*?)\);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GItPoV/3)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?ms)^set_(\w+)\((.*?)\);$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GItPoV/1).

**Details**

- `(?ms)` - multiline (`^` and `$` match start/end of the *line* now) and dotall (`.` matches line break chars) modes are ON
- `^` - start of a line
- `set_` - a literal string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `\);` - `);` substring...
- `$` - at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the values using the 2 capturing groups is to repeatedly match the key:values pairs between the opening and the closing parenthesis in group 2.

```
^set_([A-Za-z_]+)\s*\((\w+:"[^"]+"(?:, ?\w+:"[^"]+")*)\);
```

**Explanation**

- `^set_` Match `set_` form the start of the string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Za-z_]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*\(` Match 0+ whitespace chars and opening `(`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\w+:"[^"]+"` Match 1+ word chars, then from opening `"` till closing `"`
  - `(?:, ?\w+:"[^"]+")*` Optionally repeat the previous pattern preceded by a comma and optional space
- `)` Close group 2
- `\);` Match the closing `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LIKAuV/1)